# How to add bookmark in word document header programmatically?

Tags: c#, ms-word

I have done bookmark creation in word document. but, In main text part not in header and footer part. Now, I want to create bookmark in Primary Header Section.

Actually, I am trying to update text of bookmark at run time. But, whenever I change the text of bookmark it get removed. So, I have to create it again programmatically.

This is my code to replace the text of word document bookmark.

```
if (doc.Bookmarks.Exists(_bookMarkName))
{
    object oBookMark = _bookMarkName;
    //Getting Bookmark Object
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Bookmark bookmark = doc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref oBookMark);

    //calculating range to create bookmark.
    object start = bookmark.Range.Start;
    object end = bookmark.Range.Start + _value.Length;

    //After replacing this text, bookmark will be removed from the document. So, we have to creat it again.
    bookmark.Range.Text = _value;

    //Creating range from new values.
    object range = doc.Range(ref start, ref end);
    doc.Bookmarks.Add(_bookMarkName, ref range); //Adding new bookmark with new range 
}
```

So, what is the problem in this code is the `StoryType` property of `bookmark` object will be `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdStoryType.wdPrimaryHeaderStory` before replacing bookmark text. but, after creating new bookmark the property `StoryType` will be taken as `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdStoryType.wdMainTextStory` instead of `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdStoryType.wdPrimaryHeaderStory`. So, How do I change that property or assign that property when bookmark is being created. The property `StoryType` is `ReadOnly`. So, I could not assign it after creating bookmark.
`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is basically creating the new range using the doc as the starting point. SInce the Range object doesn't have a Range method, I think you would have to get the relevant StoryRange from the bookmark's range, then use GetRange to get a range in the appropriate story. I haven't checked...

...because that should not be necessary, assuming that you want the replacement bookmark to "cover" the text that you just inserted, because you should be able to do something more like this, assuming you can retranslate this VBA syntax back into C#

```
    Dim bm As Word.Bookmark
Dim bookMarkName As String
Dim doc As Word.Document
Dim newValue As String
Dim rng As Word.Range
'.
'.

If doc.Bookmarks.Exists(bookMarkName) Then
  ' Could do the following two statements in one
  Set bm = doc.Bookmarks(bookMarkName)
  Set rng = bm.Range
  rng.Text = newValue
  doc.Bookmarks.Add bookMarkName, rng
  Set rng = Nothing
  Set bm = Nothing
End If
```